# Counting up within text program?

Tags: text, counting

I am editing app code to increase floors in tiny tower.
My dilemma is I need to have a large amount of text with a single number increasing by one after some constant text repeating over and over.
Sorry, I'm not good at describing what I need so I'll show y'all an example of what I need.

```
  [Fs]**X**[Fs][Ff]58[Ff][Fl]1[Fl][Fod]0[Fod][Fsbt]1[Fsbt][Fsi]-1[Fsi][Fst]-1[Fst][Fstk]0,0,0[Fstk][Flst]0,0,0[Flst][Fn][Fn]|
```

I need this line of text repeating over and over again with the exception of the bolded **X** increasing by 1 every time the text repeats.
Such as

```
[Fs]**1**[Fs][Ff]58[Ff][Fl]1[Fl][Fod]0[Fod][Fsbt]1[Fsbt][Fsi]-1[Fsi][Fst]-1[Fst][Fstk]0,0,0[Fstk][Flst]0,0,0[Flst][Fn][Fn]|[Fs]**2**[Fs][Ff]58[Ff][Fl]1[Fl][Fod]0[Fod][Fsbt]1[Fsbt][Fsi]-1[Fsi][Fst]-1[Fst][Fstk]0,0,0[Fstk][Flst]0,0,0[Flst][Fn][Fn]|[Fs]**3**[Fs][Ff]58[Ff][Fl]1[Fl][Fod]0[Fod][Fsbt]1[Fsbt][Fsi]-1[Fsi][Fst]-1[Fst][Fstk]0,0,0[Fstk][Flst]0,0,0[Flst][Fn][Fn]|[Fs]**4**[Fs][Ff]58[Ff][Fl]1[Fl][Fod]0[Fod][Fsbt]1[Fsbt][Fsi]-1[Fsi][Fst]-1[Fst][Fstk]0,0,0[Fstk][Flst]0,0,0[Flst][Fn][Fn]| ETC...
```

I have manually written this code out to 5000 lines and I can't take it anymore. I don't know how many I need but if someone could give me either straight up the text that I need or some way for me to do it myself that would be amazing.
I need it to count up to at least 10k and id say 100k at the max.
Thanks for your help and please ask any questions if you need them answered to further help me.

Answer (score 0):

In bash you could do

```
printf '[Fs]%s[Fs][Ff]58[Ff][Fl]1[Fl][Fod]0[Fod][Fsbt]1[Fsbt][Fsi]-1[Fsi][Fst]-1[Fst][Fstk]0,0,0[Fstk][Flst]0,0,0[Flst][Fn][Fn]|\n' {1..100000} > /path/to/the/outputfile
```

To create a file `outputfile` with the first 100k lines.

On Linux or Mac open a terminal (on Windows you can use WSL, gitbash, or cygwin), type `bash`, press enter, type the command from above, press enter again.